# How to query data from array in grails

Tags: grails

I have data like this,

```
def num = [1,2,3]
```

I want to query "Role" where role's id = num

I try like

```
Role role = Role.findByID(num) or 
Role role = Role.get(num)
```

It didn't work anymore.

How can I query it ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like.

```
Role role = Role.findAllByIdInList(num) or 
Role role = Role.getAll(num)
```

Comment: what's wrong with links to the docs? http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29140994/2